# JDK 11. javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, ssl, facebook-graph-api, java-11

I'm migrating our platform to JDK 11, and one of the services has the following issue when calling to graph.facebook.com API:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/xxxxx/adaccounts": peer not authenticated; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated...
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

I've checked ca-certs on the machine, everything looks fine:

> ca-certificates is already the newest version (20180409).
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Are you using Oracle's JDK or the OpenJDK?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex, OpenJDK. Tried on both 11.0.1 and 11.0.2

Comment: OK. As far as I know, OpenJDK does ship out with a few root CA certificates but not all of them. Facebook seems to utilize a certificate provided by Eset which does not seem to be included in the list of root certs (as this is found here: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/319). Thus, to resolve the issue in question you'll need to import both the root cert for Facebook as well as possibly the intermediate ones.

Comment: I’ve found that grabbing the Root CA they provide with the PHP SDK sometimes helps, give that a try maybe - https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/tree/5.x/src/Facebook/HttpClients/certs

Answer (score 17):

You might try updating OpenJDK to 11.0.3 or higher.

I recently had a `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` show up sporadically in an app on 11.0.2, along with an occasional `SSLException: No PSK available. Unable to resume.` failure. The latter seems to be from a [known bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213202) in JDK 11.0.2. When I updated to 11.0.4, both problems disappeared.

Comment: This! We experienced SSLPeerUnverifiedException on every request to certain domain with 11.0.2. With 11.0.4, problems are gone.

Comment: I still get it with openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20 (MS build 11.0.12+7).

Comment: Yeah we actually still get this occasionally (in very bursty situations, it seems). I suspect the bugfix in 11.0.4 helped, but didn't totally fix the problem.