# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated after upgrading Spring Boot from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0.M3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I've started getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException` when making an HTTPS request to the Spring Boot based Java application from another Spring Boot based Java application (a test suite for the former) after upgrading Spring Boot from version 2.1.0 to 2.2.0.M3 in both applications. I can confirm that SSL certificate for the site is shown valid in a browser (Google Chrome), host name in there matches the one in HTTPS URL, and by just downgrading Spring Boot back to 2.1.0 I can access the URL without exception again. Oracle JDK 11.0.1 is used. SSL certificate is issued by Let's Encrypt, if this makes a difference. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Oracle JDK 11.0.4 solved the problem. I saw similar advice for OpenJDK in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224142/6460080) SO question, but decided not to mix things up for the two JDKs.